# php unix time "before 2pm today"

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp, strtotime, epoch

with PHP, I want to check if a time is "before 2pm" today

would strtotime allow something like that, or would a combination of other time/date functions get me this outcome

how would it be done?

I was thinking something like

`if(savedTime < strtotime("before 2pm today"))`

but it seems the statement isnt that good, ultimately I need both variables to be in unix/epoch time and the comparison itself will be simple, but I don't know how to get the current day's 2pm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
if($savedTime < strtotime("2pm"))
```

Comment: They seem to understand they need both times to be unix timestamps so I assumed it in my answer

Comment: Just a note for OP: also need to take account of timezone of both times.

Comment: @PauloFreitas I was thinking about that, how would I deal with timezones

Comment: @CQM Just assure both times are created with the same timezone, you might want to use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) here. :)